# How to get a sub-element of a div in front of another div?

Tags: html, css

I tried to get a sub-element of a div in front of another div, but z-index seems to work only within the div:

HTML:

```
<div class="below">
  <div class="above">Oben!</div>
</div>

<div class="middle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.below{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

.middle{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

.above{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
```

I want the classes to appear in the order: below, middle, above. Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate my Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1Blerk/jH4vX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` from `.below`

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/TLEZR/1/)

Giving an element a postion of absolute or relative, and a z-index, creates a *local stacking context*. What this means is that for any absolutely or relatively positioned children, their z-index is relative to their parent (the local stacking context), rather than to the z-index of elements outside of the parent.

If `.below` needs to be absolutely positioned, then put `.below` and `.above` in a container and give the container `position:absolute` rather than `.below`.

Comment: Is there another way? Because i want to change .below.position from absolute to fixed while scrolling, without jumping to the foreground.

Comment: As long as `.above` is in a different local stacking context than `.middle`, the z-index values of each will have no effect on which of the two appears on top. The question above doesn't cover fixed position. You may need to update the question to provide additional information and code.

Answer (score 0):

Just workout this code .

html

```
<div class="below">
 <div class="above">Oben!</div>
</div>
<div class="middle"></div>
```

css

```
.below{
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
z-index:0;
 }
.middle{
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
}
.above{
 position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```